# List/download Http folder files without parsing HTML

Tags: c#, http

My windows service needs to connect to a specific HTTP folder (IIS 7) and list the files inside and then start downloading them one by one. Is there any real professional way rather than parsing HTML tags to get the file name (which most likely will cause problems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless you have [directory browsing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725840.aspx) setup on IIS.

Is this your server or a thirdparty site you're trying to scrape? If you don't have control of the server you may not have a choice.

Comment: Thanks Nathan fro u reply ,this is 3rd party server (CDN repository)

Comment: What CDN? Most CDN's offer some sort of api for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually yes, but i use a dummy CDN, our soft is on POC stage ( Proof of concept), we'll move to real CDN once project confirmed.

Comment: If your goal is to POC a CDN, then I would suggest writing a simple API of your own that returns a list of files.